# Combined Operator Overloading in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload operators in such a way that you can capture a specific combination of them? For example lets say I have a custom object myObject of type MyType where [] is already overloaded to pass such calls down to a map object. That said, in the case of the following code:

```
int value = myObject["someProp"];
```

I'm already overloading `[]` but in this case I'd like to know when `[]` is being called on the object in an assignment, with a reference to the type of object that the property lookup is to be assigned to. This way I can cast the value coming out of the dynamic property lookup and so on and so forth. Any input is appreciated!

**For more insight into exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, [see this related question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457961/dynamic-object-in-c).**

Comment: You can't apply _any_ operators to a type like that. Well, except `...`...

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry could you elaborate? That's a poor example of code I should say myObject is of type someObject where [] is already overloaded to pass such calls to a map object.

Comment: Indeed. :) You'd better call the type `MyType`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't overload on the return type, or on the context in which the call appears (e.g. in an assignment etc).

You could, however, return a proxy object that would have a bunch of overloaded conversion operators. Without seeing what you intend to do, it's hard to say how far you might be able to get with this approach, or whether it's even a sane thing to do.

Comment: Or on what happens to the return type

Comment: Basically I'm using std::map to create a sort of dynamic property system on a certain type of object. I'm storing these types as cdiggins::any. Later, users can access these properties obviously and the reason I was thinking of knowing the type on assignment is so I can explicitly cast to the desired type (or error if it's wrong). I'm a noob so I'm probably not making much sense or at least not expressing what I mean to do very well.

Comment: @AscensionSystems: In that case, return a proxy object that contains a reference to your `any` type (consider using Boost.Any) and overload the conversion operator as a template: `template<class T> operator T&() const{ /* test and convert / fail */ }`.

Comment: Yeah I'm just in the process of trying something along those lines now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want type deduction for things like this, your best bet is to overload `operator()` instead, and pass in the thing you're going to be assigning to as a dummy parameter, i.e.:

```
MyType myObject;
int value = myObject("someProp", value);
```

I've made something like this work pretty well in the past. In particular, see e.g.:

https://github.com/sgolodetz/hesperus2/blob/master/source/engine/core/hesp/objects/base/ObjectManager.tpp

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are basically correct that you can't do it. aix hints at a solution of a custom return type with overloaded conversion operators, but rightly indicates it isn't a sane thing to do.  I've ventured down this path quite often and ultimately implicit conversions, and sequences of conversions, and ambiguities will bite you in you in the behind.

I've had a need of this quite often though. Ultimately I end up going for a series of overloaded functions, or templates, depending on your needs, perhaps like this:

```
void lookup( int& v, char const * name );
void lookup( double& c, char const * name );
```

In the template case I created global converters and did the below member function:

```
template<T>
void lookup( T&v, char const* name ) { v = convert<T>( get(name) ); }
```

If you want to keep the return value as the lookup you'll have to explicitly call a templated function.

```
   template<T> T get( char const * name ) { ... }

   //use
   int a = obj.get<int>( "name" );
   double b = obj.get<double>( "floaty" );
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it's rather straightforward to do: all that is needed is
for your operator to return a proxy which then overloads the operators
you want to catch.  In practice, it can cause more than a few problems;
readers will expect `(a op1 b) op2 c` to have
the same semantics as `T tmp(a ip1 b); tmp op2
c`.  There are some common exceptions, however:

- The `operator[]` in a multi-dimensional array will often return a
  proxy which defines an `operator[]` itself, in order to support `[][]`
  correctly.
- More generally, a container which for whatever reasons needs to know 
  when a value is modified will have an `operator[]` which returns a
  proxy; within the proxy, assignment is defined as setting the value in
  the owning container, and there will be a convertion operator to the
  value type, for use in rvalue contexts.  Of course, this means that
  things like `m[i][j].funct()` don't work; typically, however, this sort
  of thing is used for matrices of numeric types, where member functions
  aren't that relevant.
- In contexts where it is desirable to support overload resolution based
  on the target type (your example), the function can return a proxy with
  overloaded conversion operators.  You want to be extremely careful with
  this—overloaded conversion operators are often a recipe for
  overload resolution ambiguities&rdash;but there are enough exceptions
  that this situation bears mentionning.  (Important, here, is that the
  results of the operator will amost always be used to intialize or to
  assign to a specific object, the type of which determines which
  conversion operator will be called.)

BTW: I might mention that in the example you give, there is no
assignment; it is a classical initialization.  In this case, defining
the `operator[]` to return a proxy which defines `operator int() const`
would do the trick very well.  Before going this route, however, you
should very definitely consider all of the use cases of your class, and
ensure that there are none in which the actual target type is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.

Moreso, madness that way lies!

Comment: I understand it's ridiculous to be honest, but unfortunately I'm being forced down this terrible path of trying to accommodate language features from an entirely different language... to the best extent that I can. Leh sigh... to way of madness it must be.

Comment: @AscensionSystems: Well, as my first sentence indicates, you are prohibited by the language from going down that path!