# Is there a C++ equivalent of java.lang.Number?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, vector, type-conversion

I am trying to create a `std::vector` that could take in any kind of numeric data type (char, short, int, long, float and double) in C++ .

In java, I could create  `List<Number> list = ArrayList<Number>();`

Is there an equivalent in C++ (Preferably <=C++03). If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

PS -  I really do not want to have one vector for each data type :/

Comment: How about type-erasure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Class wrapper around fundamental types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793298/c-class-wrapper-around-fundamental-types)

Comment: Unions are maybe something for you.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann I looked at Unions. But this would mean I always allocate 64 bits for every vector element. If someone wants to  read in just 1GB of 8 bit data, I would take up 8GB of RAM which I do not want to do. Is this the case or have I misunderstood how unions work?

Comment: You cannot store elements of different sizes in a vector. Neither in C++ nor in Java. Java actually stores references of the actual objects in this case. So you also have to store 64 bits for each entry. In C++ you could use pointers, but I am not sure if that is worth it.

Comment: Ok I did not word that properly. What I meant was, even if I store the pointer to the union in the vector, the union itself will take up 64 bits for each entry -- even though most of the time I need only 8 or 16 bits. In java, I could create the object of that particular data type and store its reference in a list.

Comment: I asked something kind of similar regarding statically and dynamically typed languages here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561492/c-and-dynamically-typed-languages. Have a look to the answers, they might help you.

Comment: You could put union itself in vector. In Java, you could use `Number` but remember that `Number` is object, and every object adds 8 bytes of overhead, then 4 bytes for reference. Add padding, and your "8 bit integer" boxed in Java takes 16 bytes + 4 bytes for reference = 160 bits (on 32-bit Java; on 64-bit it's even worse). C++ union still wins by large margin.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/258150/226648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way for what you want is:

```
enum datatype
{
    dt_none,
    dt_char,
    dt_uchar,
    dt_short,
    dt_ushort,
    dt_long,
    dt_ulong,
    dt_float,
    dt_double
};

struct Any
{
      datatype type; // To know what is stored inside union, not mandatory if you know that in another way
      union
      {
          char vchar;
          unsigned char vuchar;
          short vshort;
          unsigned short vushort;
          long vlong;
          unsigned long vulong;
          float vfloat;
          double vdouble;
      } data;
};

std::vector<Any> mydata;
```

You can avoid using an union, but it take more memory (pointer for every value + real size) and it's more complicated to use:

```
struct Any
{
     private:
         void * data;
         datatype type;

     public:
         Any():
             data(NULL),
             type(dt_none)
         {}

         ~Any()
         {
             deleteData();  
         }

         void deleteData()
         {
             // Because deleting a void * is UB, we have to check real datatype
             if (data != NULL)
             {
                 if (type == dt_char)
                     delete static_cast<char *>(data);
                 if (type == dt_uchar)
                     delete static_cast<unsigned char *>(data);
                 ....
             }   
         }

         datatype getType() const
         {
             return type;
         }

         void setChar(char v)
         {
             deleteData(); 
             data = new char(v);
             type = dt_char;
         } 


         char toChar() const
         {
             return *static_cast<char *>(data);
         } 

         .....

         void setDouble(double v)
         {
             deleteData();
             data = new double(v);
         }

         double toDouble() const
         {
             return *static_cast<double*>(data);
         }
};
```

A possible optimization, is using pointer to store small type data, to save some bytes (but do it carefully!). But if you store a lot of big type data, `union` still better. Also, size of a pointer is platform dependent, so it's difficult to choose which type can be store directly in pointer and have a portable code. Also, on 64bits computer, size of pointer is 8 bytes, which is also common size of `double` (so, is this case, store directly every type inside pointer, which is same memory consumption than `union` but in a really more complicated and unsecure way ):

```
struct Any
{
     private:
         void * data;
         datatype type;

     public:
         Any():
             data(NULL),
             type(dt_none)
         {}

         ~Any()
         {
             deleteData();
         }

         void deleteData()
         {
             // Because deleting a void * is UB, we have to check real datatype
             if (type != dt_char && type != dt_uchar && data != NULL)
             {
                 if (type == dt_double)
                     delete static_cast<double *>(data);
                 ....
             } 
             data = NULL;
         }

         datatype getType() const
         {
             return type;
         }

         void setChar(char v)
         {
             data = reinterpret_cast<void *>(v);
         } 


         char toChar() const
         {
             return static_cast<char>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(data));
         } 

         .....

         void setDouble(double v)
         {
             deleteData();
             data = new double(v);
         }

         double toDouble() const
         {
             return *static_cast<double*>(data);
         }
};
```

All that to say you have only 2 simple solutions in your case (IMHO):

- if you really want to save memory, your have to use a vector per type.
- or use `union`

PS: You can also take a look at third party library like [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html).